# Plotly line chart - multiple lines

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I want to create a line chart with three lines (male,female,unknown). This is a sample of my data:

```
timestamp;sex;number
06:00;male;5
07:00;male;2
07:00;unkown;3
07:00;female;4
09:00;female;4
```

Is there a option in plotly to automatically create the three lines or do I need to loop through the data and create three traces by myself? This is my code so far:

```
var trace1 = {
  type: 'scatter',
  x: x,
  y: y,
  name: "Male",
  transforms: [{
    type: 'aggregate',
    groups: x,
    aggregations: [
      {target: 'y', func: 'count', enabled: true},
    ]
  }]
};


var data = [trace1];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {title: 'Plotting CSV data from AJAX call'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create different data set(trace) for each category.

 Maybe [this](https://codepen.io/mdnasirfardoush/pen/pXJmQb) can help you.

```
var men = {
  x: x, 
  y: y, 
  type: 'scatter',
  name:'male'
};

var female = {
  x: x, 
  y: y, 
  type: 'scatter',
  'name':'female'
};
var unknown = {
  x: x, 
  y:y, 
  type: 'scatter',
  'name':'unknown'
};

var data = [men, female,unknown];
```

Comment: ok so there is no option like: "split: gender" that split the data and create the traces automatically?

Comment: Hi @ZerOne Plotly not provided this feature yet as far I know.